# Display unique array entries and sum of related entry from separate array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to take two arrays that are related, filter one to retrieve the unique values and the other needs to have the sums for the unique values. The indexes for Array 1 match the index for Array 2 that I need to add all the values together to get the sum. For example:

Array 1:

```
var arr1 = [7012, 7013, 7015, 7012];
```

Array 2:

```
var arr2 = [10, 20, 25, 10];
```

Expected Output:

(first explanation was not great, changing this)

```
newArray1 = [7012, 7013, 7015];
newArray2 = [20, 20, 25];
```

Note: I am using Firebase to retrieve the values into the arrays, these are not going to be set indexes.

I'm using Set() to retrieve the unique values:

```
var newArr = [...new Set(arr1)];
```

which works perfectly fine.

The trouble I'm having is getting the related values from Array 2 and making a sum. I can create the sum fine by using .reduce() but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the Array 2 values into a new array based on what they're related to in Array 1.

Comment: are the values for the same value in array1 equal? why not use Set for array 2? and then add the unique values?

Comment: which sums? arr[0]+arr2[0] or what? what happens if the arrays have different lengths? Why do you need this ( may be an XY problem)

Comment: Your example doesn't show your expected output. As it stands it is not clear which values you would like to include in your sum.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the expected output. It would look like this:
7012: 20
7013: 20
7015: 25

Essentially I need to add together the sum of array2 values with the same indexes of the unique values for array1 but before I make the values unique.

Comment: @TaylorNellis please edit your quesition, and 7012:20 is an object property

Comment: @TaylorNellis So you want to do it based on the first position of each unique value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want an array that will include the respective sums from array2 for the unique values of array1. Using a `Map` we can get the unique values, and the corresponding sums. You can then use `Map#values` to get the sums of array2, `Map#keys` to get the unique values of array1, and `map#entries` to get tuples of unique value and sum.

```js
const arr1 = [7012, 7013, 7015, 7012];
const arr2 = [10, 20, 25, 10];

const map = arr1.reduce((map, v, i) => {
  const sum = map.get(v) || 0;
  
  return map.set(v, sum + arr2[i]);
}, new Map());

const arr1Unique = [...map.keys()];
const arr2Sums = [...map.values()];
const tuples = [...map.entries()];

console.log(arr1Unique);
console.log(arr2Sums);
console.log(tuples);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. My explanation wasn't very good but you got it. I didn't know you could use map in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and store the corresponding values with the same keys of `array1`. Then get the values for summing.

```js
var array1 = [7012, 7013, 7015, 7012],
    array2 = [10, 20, 25, 10],
    map = array1.reduce((m, k, i) => (m.set(k, (m.get(k) || 0) + array2[i])), new Map),
    sum = [...map.values()].reduce((r, v) => r + v, 0);

console.log([...map]);
console.log(sum);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That would work fine if I needed to just get a total sum of array2 unique values. I need the array 2 values to stay not unique so that I can get the correct totals for each unique value in array1.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you, you want to group and sum up arr2, based on equal values at the arr1. So you may create a hash table:

```
var arr1 = [7012, 7013, 7015, 7012];
var arr2 = [10, 20, 25, 10];

var obj={};
arr1.forEach(function(el,i){//el is a value of arr1 at index i, e.g. 7012,0
  obj[el]=obj[el]||0;//initialise obj[7012]
  obj[el]+=arr2[i]||0;//increase obj[7012] by arr2[0] so 10
});

console.log(obj);
```

Will create:

```
{
7012:20,
7013:20,
7015:25
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) to replace the values of your unique array with the value in the corresponding position of arr2, and then use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=control) to get the sum:

```
const sum = [...new Set(arr1)].
  map( x => arr2[ arr1.indexOf( x ) ] ).
  reduce( ( a, b ) => a + b, 0 )
;
```